# Dose response meta analysis : Error on quadratic model

Tags: r, metafor

I am currently trying dose-response meta-analysis using the command `dosresmeta`.
I used the dataset (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IacL0-k3GvcQjv9uRZXMimEkrBJmd7NG/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=102840177676341943440&rtpof=true&sd=true)

When I tried to test for quadratic model, the commands returned error:

```
library(dosresmeta)
quad_drma<-dosresmeta(formula = logrr ~ dose + I(dose^2), type = type, id = id,
                                 se = se, cases = event.n, n = total.n, data = datafile)
summary(quad_drma)
```

This is the error code.

```
dosresmeta.fit(X[v != 0, , drop = FALSE], Z[v != 0, , drop = FALSE] :
  A two-stage approach requires that each study provides at least p non-referent obs (p is the number of columns of the design matrix X)
```

I tried to figure out the problem, and when I altered `I(dose^2)` to `dose^2` the code worked but wrong results were came out.

Does anyone know which part of my code or dataset caused problem?
I tried to figure out but I could not solve this problem.

Comment: Have you checked if "each study provides at least p non-referent obs (p is the number of columns of the design matrix X)"?

Comment: `I(dose^2)` and `dose^2` are not the same, see `?formula` and `?I`

Comment: Hi Roland, thank you for replying. Can you explain how I can check ""each study provides at least p non-referent obs (p is the number of columns of the design matrix X)"? I am new to statistics, so it is bit difficult to me.

Comment: Hi rawr, thanks for replying. I know that 'I(dose^2)' and 'dose^2' are different, but I just tried just in case it works. But as I mentioned, I found that it shows wrong answers so it is not appropriate.  However, when I used other datasheet then I(dose^2) worked properly.. so I think it is data problem but I don't know why this data causes problem. Can you advice me how I can solve this? Thank you so much,